Is the rank of a homogeneous tensor preserved by the quotient map which sends the tensor to the exterior power of the same grade?
Let $T^n(V)$ be the $n$-th tensor power of $V$. Let $A$ be a rank $k$ tensor in $T^n(V)$, meaning that $A$ is a sum of at least $k$ simple tensors in $T^n(V)$.
The rank of an element of the exterior power has the same definition as the rank in the tensor power.
$T^n(V)$ maps into the $n$-th exterior power of $V$ via the well-known quotient map. How does the rank in the exterior power relate to the rank in the tensor power?
It seems that the rank in the exterior power would be less than or equal to the rank in the tensor power, with equality on alternating tensors.

"It seems that..." Why are you unsure? "...with equality on alternating tensors." No, just consider $v\otimes w - w\otimes v$ with independent $v,w$; this has rank 2 but maps to (a multiple of) $v\wedge w$.

@NicholasTodoroff Thanks, that's a great observation. Really, what I'm trying to do is prove that rank in the exterior algebra is invariant under the action of the general linear group. This seems obvious from the definition since it sounds basis-invariant, but I can't think of a straightforward proof. I was hoping to inherit the property from the tensor algebra. Any idea how to make the connection?

No tensor algebra required. Let $f$ be the outermorphism of some transformation and let the rank of some multivector $X$ be $r$. Suppose $f(X)$ has lower rank, and write it in the corresponding form. Now apply $f^{-1}$ to conclude that $X$ can be written with less than $r$ terms, a contradiction. Finally, if $f$ increases the rank of $X$, then $f^{-1}$ decreases the rank of $f(X)$, which it can't, so $f$ must preserve rank.

Note that the exact same argument works over any (non-unital) ring with some generating set defining rank and $f$ an automorphism.

@NicholasTodoroff Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.
